# differences of linear and nonlinear data structures( advantages and disadvantages)?

Tags: data-structures

I know what linear and nonlinear data structures is ,but could someone explain me in 2-3 phrases what the differences is?
It would like to have the differences about the two of them and not the definition what it is (like here):
http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-linear-and-vs-nonlinear-data-structures/

Comment: That's a pretty broad question. What is it that you really want to know?

Answer (score 1):

> explain me in 2-3 phrases what the differences is?

Linear means that they are represented by one (single) series of data ... i.e Each data member has at most one predecessor and at most one successor.

Non-linear means anything else.

[image]

Comment: "means anything else"what do you mean with that?

Comment: @DcDaniel17 its means that each data member can have more than one predecessor and successor.
`Non-linear means anything else` means that any data-structure that is not **linear** will be **non-linear**

Comment: and the advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 0):

**Linear data structure**

1. Data is stored in memory in linear or sequential order.
2. It use the pointer.
3. It is easy to implement.
4. Single level is involved.
5. Memory utilization is ineffetive.
6. Eg:-array, link list, stack and queue.

**Non-linear data structure**

1. Data is stored randomly in memory.
2. It doesnot use pointer.
3. It is comparatively difficult to implement.
4. Multiple level is involved.
5. Memory utilization is effective.
6. Eg:-tree and graph.

Answer (score 0):

in linear data structure , data is stored in the memory in sequential or linear manner and one element has at most one predecessor and at most one successor . it has single level.

if it is non linear data structure , data is stored in the memory in random order and it has multiple level.